# Files associated with Thunderbird - Security mechanism for local storage

Tags: files, security, email, thunderbird

I am trying to know how Thunderbird stores the mails, associated files in the local machine.
I use Ubuntu 13.10 and Thunderbird 24.6.0.

When I see in the local profile folder in the location in `~/.thunderbird`, there exists a profile folder say `SomeRandomSequence.default`. For my experiments, I listed the files inside that folder without opening Thunderbird, and then listed again after I opened the Thunderbird.

Here is what I found:

- Among the files, a file called `session.json` will be there in the
  folder, when Thunderbird is not open. (It will vanish when I open
  Thunderbird)
- When Thunderbird is opened, as told earlier, `session.json` will
  vanish and the below files will appear.

  ```
  - lrwxrwxrwx 1 sid sid       16 okt    6 13:41 lock -> 127.0.1.1:+13149
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid        0 okt    6 13:41 cookies.sqlite-wal
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid    32768 okt    6 13:41 cookies.sqlite-shm
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid        0 okt    6 13:41 webappsstore.sqlite-wal
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid    32768 okt    6 13:41 webappsstore.sqlite-shm
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid        0 okt    6 13:41 places.sqlite-wal
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid    32768 okt    6 13:41 places.sqlite-shm
  - -rw-r--r-- 1 sid sid   721584 okt    6 13:41 global-messages-db.sqlite-journal
  ```

Also, I tried to change the INBOX file of both IMAP and POP folders (keeping my Thunderbird closed), expecting the changes I made (say I added some line in some particular mail) would appear in the Thunderbird client. (Of course the computer was connected to Internet). But I could see no change.

1. What is preventing me from seeing those changes in the Thunderbird
   mail client?
2. If I want to see the changes, how can I do it?

Any help to make my understanding better will be much much appreciated.